# How can I deploy a laravel app on Bluehost?

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting

I'm having challenge deploying a laravel 5.4 app on Bluehost. I was successful deploying similar web app on a different host (web4africa) and tried following similar steps but getting **HTTP ERROR 500**.

This is what I have done so far.

1. Loaded all folders and files except the laravel public folder to root directory /home/ppikogco
2. Moved the contents inside laravel public folder into /home/ppikogco/public_html
3. Changed autoload path in /home/ppikogco/public/html/index.php to  `require _DIR_.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';` and `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`

In error_log file, the following error is being thrown

> [09-Feb-2018 04:25:09] PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home2/ppikogco/public_html/index.php on line 52
>   [09-Feb-2018 04:25:09] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home2/ppikogco/public_html/index.php on line 52

This is line 52 of the index.php and the line of code before it

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
// $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../ppikog/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
```

I need help figuring out what I'm doing wrong or how to fix the issue.

Comment: Start by checking your hosts error logs.

Comment: From the error_log I can see just one error referring to line 52 of /home/ppikogco/public_html/index.php

This is the line `$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
`
I have no idea at this point

Comment: Okay, and what does the error message say?

Comment: So you think __we__ can read your error logs? Or maybe you will be kind and post exact error message?

Comment: Exact error messgae - `[09-Feb-2018 04:25:09] PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home2/ppikogco/public_html/index.php on line 52
[09-Feb-2018 04:25:09] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home2/ppikogco/public_html/index.php on line 52
`

Comment: Can you add line 52 and the preceding couple of lines to your question please.

Comment: [edit] link is here.

Comment: `and the preceding couple of lines`

Comment: @JonStirling I have edited my question to include line 52 and preceding lines of the index.php file

Comment: Preceding, i.e. lines _before_ 52.

Comment: @JonStirling correction made to question

Comment: What version of PHP is your host running...?

Comment: @JonStirling I discovered that the php version isn't set automatically, so I set it to 7.0 since 5.4 requires PHP version >= 5.6. Now I see laravel error page `(1/1) InvalidArgumentException
View [index] not found.`

Comment: Can't help with that one. Probably worth closing this one and asking a new question specific to that issue.

Comment: @JonStirling Alright post your answer so i can accept it as the right answer